# Algorithm for grouping tetrahedra from Voronoi diagram

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

I have a set of 3D Voronoi generator points and their neighbouring points, which, when connected, should result in a Delaunay tetrahedralization. However, I'm having a hard time implementing this. My main problem is grouping the neighbouring vertices to form individual tetrahedra, and I'm uncertain about the best approach for this task. I've already tried to explore Delaunay triangulation algorithms, but my situation should be simpler since I already have all the vertices and edges.

All I could come up with is to iterate through all the neighbours of a vertex to identify sets of four vertices that are mutually neighbours, forming a single tetrahedron. However, this method seems quite slow if I have to do this for every vertex as I will get a lot of duplicates.

Any resources that provide information on algorithms for finding the dual graph or pseudocode is greatly appreciated.

EDIT for @Iddo Hanniel:

This image shows a triangulation with 3 tetrahedra. If I just use a naive method of finding 4 voronoi points (tetra vertices) that are all mutually neighbors then the 'top' and 'bottom' tetrahedra will also be counted. That would lead to a total of 5 tetrahedra. (3 with the shared vertical edge + the 'top' and 'bottom')
To fix this I had to manually check the circumsphere condition where no other points lie in the circumsphere of each tetrahedron. For the 'top' and 'bottom' tetrahedra this condition is not satisfied and thus they don't belong to the triangulation. If they did the 3 tetrahedra would intersect with the 'top' and 'bottom'.

Now I'm not all that concerned about runtime since this triangulation is a non critical part of the code. But it would be nice to speed it up a bit especially by not having to do this circumsphere condition.

[image: 3 tetrahedra]

Comment: Did your upstream calculation provide the Voronoi vertices? You could sort the nearby Delaunay vertices according to distance from a Voronoi vertex and the tetrahedral vertices will all be tied, which should be easy and fast to notice. Maybe they're all tied for first even?

Comment: how did you find the neighbors without calculating Delaunay? If your problem is to compute the Delaunay triangulation, you should use a Delaunay triangulation algorithm!

Comment: The Voronoi cells are calculated using voro++, this should also give the Voronoi vertices. 
JohnWiltshire-Gordon, so you're saying I should look for the 4 equidistant Delauney vertices from this Voronoi vertex right?
alesia, I don't think voro++ uses Delaunay internally, but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chapter 27](https://www.csun.edu/%7Ectoth/Handbook/chap27.pdf) of [The Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry](https://www.csun.edu/%7Ectoth/Handbook/HDCG3.html)
enumerates the complexity of known Delaunay triangulation algorithms of any dimension (see Table 27.2.1 there).

For 3D Delaunay the worst-case runtime is $O(n^2)$ and the expected complexity for uniform distributed points
(for which the complexity of the result triangulation is expected to be linear) is $O(n\ log\ n)$.

In the question comments a possible algorithm suggests to use the Voronoi vertices (which are the centers of the Delaunay spheres)
to collect the closest four points to tetrahedra.
However, for this to work you will need a proximity search structure such as a [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Building a kd-tree will already take $O(n\ log\ n)$ and each query to find the closest points will take $O(log\ n)$,
which means that this algorithm will take $O(|T|\ log\ n)$, where $|T|$ is the number of tetrahedra in the triangulation
(which is the number of vertices in the dual Voronoi diagram).

Note: The number of tetrahedra in a 3D Delaunay triangulation can be $O(n^2)$.
The figure below demonstrates such a quadratic configuration.
It consists of $n/2$ ($n=20$ in the figure) points along the line $y=0; z=3$, and $n/2$ points along the line $x=0; z=-3$
(the drawing was done with functions from the StackOverflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284599/9702190)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777239/9702190)).

The complexity of the Delaunay triangulation for such a configuration is $(n/2 - 1)(n/2 - 1) = O(n^2)$ as each of the
$(n/2 -1)$ edges on one line has $(n/2 - 1)$ tetrahedra incident to it.

[image: Quadratic complexity Delaunay triangulation]

The black line-segments are drawn to give the intuition behind this construction.
They are finite edges of the dual Voronoi diagram of the points, and each square is a portion of
a bisector plane which is equidistant from two input points.
Each point therefore has $n/2$ faces on the boundary of its Voronoi cell (in the figure only $8 = n/2 - 2$ are seen since
the first and last faces are infinite and I only draw finite edges).

As a side note, it is not suprising that these faces approximate a hyperbolic surface, as such a surface is the bisector *surface* of
two 3D lines (see [this paper by Elber and Kim](https://gershon.cs.technion.ac.il/papers/bisect3d.pdf), for example).

So, $|T|$ can be $O(n^2)$ in the worst case.
Therefore, an algorithm that collects tetrahedra using such queries on the Voronoi vertices will either not improve (over the
uniform distributed $O(n\ log\ n)$ case), or worsen (over the worst-case) the runtime complexity compared to standard Delaunay
algorithms.

The other direction, which you suggested in the question can be developed into the following algorithm.
Basically, for each edge $(v_i, v_j)$ take all out-edges $(v_i, v_k)$ from $v_i$ and find all out-edges $(v_j, v_k)$ with same
end-vertex to collect all triangles around the edge.
With some hashing on the edges this should be linear in the out degrees of the vertices.

Once you have the surrounding triangles, you can sort them geometrically in a cyclic order around the edge, i.e., sort them by the angle of
the triangle-plane normal around the edge.
Each pair of neighboring triangles can then be connected to a tetrahedron
(and tetrahedra connectivity information can also be stored in this stage).
The runtime of this procedure is dominated by the sorting, which should take $O(m_{ij}\ log\ m_{ij})$, where $m_{ij}$ is the out-degrees of the vertices.

So the total run-time of this procedure is $O(\sum_{ij \in E} m_{ij}\ log\ m_{ij})$.
The runtime can probably be improved with some shortcuts and book-keeping/hashing, but the asymptotic runtime will probably be the same.

EDIT: Following the comments and the edit in the question, we can see that the above method is not sufficient, since there can be tetrahedra which do not appear in the Delaunay. However, this means that their corresponding circumcenter will not appear as a vertex in the input Voronoi.
Therefore, an enhancement to the method to handle this, which will not increase the asymptotic runtime, can be as follows:
Store the Voronoi vertices in a hash table, and for every tetrahedron compute it's circumcenter (e.g., as in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777239/9702190)) and check in O(1) whether it appears in the hash table.

Now, as the example above shows, $m_{ij}$ can be $O(n)$ and the number of edges $|E|$ can be $O(n^2)$, so the above run-time of this procedure
in the worst case (e.g., in the example from the figure) can be $O(n^3\ log\ n)$.

In the case of uniform distributed points, however, the triangulation is expected to be $O(n)$ and the out-degrees
bound by some constant. In this case $O(m_{ij}\ log\ m_{ij})$ is constant and the run-time will be $O(n)$, which is an improvement over
the $O(n\ log\ n)$ run-time of the standard algorithms.

Having said that, I tend to agree with @alesia. The standard Delaunay algorithms have good and tested implementations.
And implementing your own for an improvement factor of $log\ n$, is generally not worth the time IMO.

If you do decide to implement it, you can implement a hybrid method.
The hybrid method can
decide between a standard algorithm and your own based on the complexity of
the Delaunay and the maximal out-degree, which you can easily get from your input.

Note that just the linear complexity of the Delaunay is not sufficient in its own and the maximal out-degree condition is also required.
This can be seen in the example figure below (which is a variation on the above configuration), where the Delaunay
triangulation is linear, but since there is a single edge with $O(n)$ out-degree, the sorting around it (and therefore the total runtime)
will take $O(n\ log\ n)$.

[image: linear DT with edge complexity]

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer! 
I have a k-d tree of the voronoi points, so I can collect the 4 nearest points per voronoi vertex right? 
Regarding the other method you explained, where you sort triangles and form tetrahedra that way. Does every tetrahedron built this way have no other points in its circumsphere? Because my naive method I described in my question doesn't check this and actually builds overlapping tetrahedra. I had to make sure this constraint was satisfied. It sounds like your method would have the same problem, not sure though.

Comment: The problem with the kdtree method is that it doesn't improve the runtime over the standard Delaunay - so I wouldn't recommend it. It is O(n log n) for uniform case and O(n^2 log n) for the worst case.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean by overlapping tetrahedra. Around a given edge, you connect the neighboring faces - so the tetrahedra overlap just at a shared triangle face. It is true that you will encounter the same tetrahedron when you iterate over each of its six edges, but you don't have to enumerate it twice (e.g. you can store it as a sorted verex indices 4-tuple and keep a hash of already computed tetrahedra). The re-iteration is probably required to get neighboring tetrahedra information anyway.

Comment: I edited my question to include an example of such intersecting tetrahedra. In a 2D triangulation this problem never arises, but in 3D I have to manually check the circumsphere condition before 'counting' a tetrahedron. I think the method you described would have the same problem.

Comment: You're right, thank you, I didn't take it into consideration. But I think the method can be modified without adding to the runtime complexity. The idea: instead of checking the circumsphere condition explicitly (which, as I understand, incurs an overhead of at least O(log n) for each tetrahedron), one can hash the Voroni vertices from the input and check (in O(1)) each tetrahedron by computing its cicumsphere  center and looking it up in the hash table. What do you think?

Comment: That's a good idea! I'm assuming I need to make the hash approximate such that floats that are close will have the same hash right? Also is there really no other way to avoid calculating the circumcenter? It is quite a big/slow calculation. I know this circumsphere condition is also equivalent to maximizing the minimal angles, but I'm not sure if I can use this explicitly.

Comment: Yes, if you're using floats some rounding or approximation will be needed in the hash.

Comment: The maximal minimum angle property is only true for plane Delaunay triangulations see for (a counter) example Figure 4.1 (p. 59) in Shewchuk's  paper: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/meshpapers/delnotes.pdf However, calculating the circumcenter is not that big IMO, it amounts to solving a 3x3 linear system and you only compute it once for each tetrahedron (see my SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777239/9702190 for python code that does this).

Comment: I edited my answer according to our discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Delaunay triangulation code. It's in fact not even possible to find it just from the neighbor graph.

Think of a Delaunay edge belonging to exactly 3 Delaunay tetrahedra : you'd get overlapping tetrahedra when trying to derive the triangulation just from the graph.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be possible, this should just be the dual of a given Voronoi graph. Assuming a nice graph where no Voronoi vertex has more than 4 Voronoi points equidistant from it, it should be unique. Or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: No, re read the example in my answer

Comment: It's impossible from the Delaunay graph alone, which was your question. Now you are talking about Voronoi graph, where the vertices are the Voronoi vertices, but that's a different question

Comment: I have the Voronoi generator points (= Delaunay vertices) and their neighbours. I want to group them to make tetrahedra. So the dual of the Voronoi graph. What I was saying about the Voronoi vertices just means that the dual graph is unique.